# How to order apps in App Launcher via metadata deployment (need to move our app on top for every new orgs setup in CI)

Tags: metadata, automation, app, app-launcher

We would like to move our application on top in App Launcher, so that users do not have trouble finding it. The ultimate goal is to have this automated in our CI/CD pipelines, so that each new orgs setup would be configured like that.

The question here is: how can we achieve this via metadata deployment, api call or whatever. So far we've tried already to retrieve **AppMenu** metadata and deploy it back after reordering items, but it ends up with **Internal Error** on deploy. It still deploys back successfully if no changes made after retrieve (which is useless, of course).

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]